# How to plot a geometric average line between different tickers

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to find a way to plot a line that is the average between a few tickers (about 10). I'm at BTCUSD chart and combining about 10 other crypto prices, they are all %. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below, it calculates 10 period moving average:

```
//@version=4

//© "Shashi Kotte"

study(shorttitle = "Shashi Kotte - MA", title="Moving Average", overlay=true)

MALen = input(10, title="MA Lenth")

MoVa = sma(close, MALen)

plot(MoVa, color=color.purple, linewidth=4)
```